# What do PGROUNDUP and PGROUNDDOWN in xv6 mean?

Tags: c, operating-system, xv6

In xv6 `mmu.h` file, there are these 2 lines of code

```
    #define PGROUNDUP(sz)  (((sz)+PGSIZE-1) & ~(PGSIZE-1))
    #define PGROUNDDOWN(a) (((a)) & ~(PGSIZE-1))
```

What do they do?

Comment: "round up" and "round down" might be inferred from the names.  And given "mmu", PG probably means "page".

Comment: the important thing to know is that `~` is the bitwise NOT operator

Comment: Thanks @OliverCharlesworth, my understanding is that, if I replace "sz" in PGROUNDUP with the size of the current running process, it will return the size of all pages allocated to the process, and divide that by the size of a single page, then we get the number of pages allocated to that process. Do you think that is correct?

Comment: Thanks @bruceg, do you think my understanding up there is correct?

Comment: @K.Wu I'm not too sure about that.  It looks like PGROUNDUP is rounding up a size to the next multiple of PGSIZE, while PGROUNDDOWN is rounding down to the previous multiple of PGSIZE.  If your PGSIZE is 1024, then PGROUNDUP(1099) would be 2048, while PGROUNDDOWN(1099) would be 1024.  So, if the size of your current running process is 1099, there would be two pages allocated.  Is that what you're thinking?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`PGROUNDUP` and `PGROUNDDOWN` are macros to round the address sent to a multiple of the `PGSIZE`. These are generally used to obtained page aligned address. `PGROUNDUP` will round the address to the higher multiple of `PGSIZE` while `PGROUNDDOWN` will round it to the lower multiple of `PGSIZE`.

Let us take an example if `PGROUNDUP` is called on a system with `PGSIZE` 1KB with the address 620:

- PGROUNDUP(620) ==> ((620 + (1024 -1)) & ~(1023)) ==> 1024
- The address 620 was rounded up to 1024.

Similarly for `PGROUNDDOWN` consider:

- PGROUNDDOWN(2400) ==> (2400 & ~(1023)) ==> 2048
- The address 2400 was rounded down to 2048.

Answer (score 0):

First you should know (PGSIZE-1)) is the max remainder (addr/page_size)

- round down

Essentially we only need to abandon the remainder part,and & ~(PGSIZE-1)) makes the thing

- round up